# How can i change only black color in white using opencv python without pixel operation

Tags: python, opencv

[This is the sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEocv.jpg)

I want to change the black color in the image into white.
I tried using threshold and bitwise operations but these operations distorts the other color present in the image.
I don't want to use pixel operations as these are expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a threshold operation on your source image using `cv2.THRESH_INV` argument, to ensure that only the black pixels change to white and the other pixels turn black.

Convert the binary mask to a 3 channel image by using:

```
src1_mask=cv2.cvtColor(src1_mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)#change mask to a 3 channel image
```

use cv2.addWeighted method to add the mask and the original image. The black part of the mask will be replaced by the original image and the white part will remain white, since the black pixels will be approximately 0 in the addWeighted operation

Answer (score 0):

Load your source image as an array named 'img' and then do this:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = cv2.compare(gray,5,cv2.CMP_LT)
img[mask > 0] = 255
```